# Chebyshev's Inequality proof explanation - squared values of probability

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, intuition

In the proof of Chebyshev's Inequality we do the following:

Claim: for some random variable $Y$ and some value $a > 0$

$Pr[|Y - E[Y]| \geq a] = \frac{E[(Y - E[Y])^2]}{a^2}$

Let's refer to $E[Y]$ as $\mu$

\begin{align*}
Pr[|Y - \mu| \geq a] =&\  Pr[|Y - \mu|^2 \geq a^2] \\
=& \ Pr[X \geq a^2]\ \ \ \ if \ X = (Y - \mu)^2\\
\leq& \ \frac{E[X]}{a^2}\ \ \ \ by \ Markov's \ inequality\\
=& \ \frac{E[(Y - E[Y])^2]}{a^2}
\end{align*}

My question is, how can we just assert:

$Pr[|Y - \mu| \geq a] =\  Pr[|Y - \mu|^2 \geq a^2]$

What is the intuition or line of thought behind this?

Comment: Do you mean “intuition” by “institution” in the last line?

Comment: Yes, corrected, thank you

Comment: Here's a related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4245789/inequalities-in-chebyshev-s-inequality-and-chernoff-bounds-proofs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claim: $|Y-\mu|\ge a$ holds $\Leftrightarrow$ $|Y-\mu|^2\ge a^2$ holds.

Proof:

In general, if $g$ is a non-decreasing real valued function then applying $g$ to both sides of an inequality preserves the inequality.

"$\Rightarrow$": Let $g(x) = x^2$ for $x\ge0$ and $g(x)=x$ for $x<0.$

"$\Leftarrow$": Let $g(x) = \sqrt x$ for $x\ge0$ and $g(x)=x$ for $x<0.$

This shows that the events are identical, so their probabilities are equal.

---

Here's another way to think about this:

Imagine the probabilities were not the same. Suppose $P(|Y-\mu|\ge a)>P(|Y-\mu|^2\ge a^2).$ Then with positive probability, $|Y-\mu|\ge a$ holds but $|Y-\mu|^2\ge a^2$ does not hold, which is a contradiction. Similiarly, the second probability can't be greater. Therefore they must be equal.

Comment: I see but then how can $P(x \geq a) = P[g(x) \geq g(a)]$. It would make sense if this was function was applied to both sides of the equation.

Comment: @SamP The function is applied to both sides to the inequality. This shows that the events $|Y-\mu|\ge a$ and $|Y-\mu|^2\ge a^2$ are identical, so their probabilities are the same.

Comment: Your second explanation is a neat way of seeing this. I very much appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see it is that
$$\mathbb{P}(|X|\geq a)=\mathbb{E}\left[1_{|X|\geq a}\right]$$
Now look at the indicator function:
$$1_{|X|\geq a}=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }|X|\geq a\\
0 & \text{if}\,|X|<a
\end{cases}=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }|X|^{2}\geq a^{2}\\
0 & \text{if}\,|X|^{2}<a^{2}
\end{cases}$$
As it preserves inequalities in this setting. Meaning: $1_{|X|\geq a}=1_{|X|^{2}\geq a^{2}}$. It is the same analogy as Epiousios, but just specifying that the indicator function is equal in both cases.