# Inequalities in Chebyshev’s Inequality and Chernoff Bounds proofs

Tags: probability-theory

Following this book

**Probability and Computing: Randomization and Probabilistic Techniques in Algorithms and
Data Analysis** Second Edition; Michael Mitzenmacher and Eli Upfal

they show Chebyshev’s Inequality (page 51)

$$
\Pr(|X - \mathbb{E}[X]| \geq a) \leq \frac{\mathbb{Var}[X]}{a^2}
$$

and start the proof by this "trick"

> We first observe that

$$
\Pr(|X - \mathbb{E}[X]| \geq a) = \Pr((X - \mathbb{E}[X])^2 \geq a^2)
$$

If we ignore the mean and assume non-negative values of X, it basically says

$$
\Pr(X \geq a) = \Pr(X^2 \geq a^2)
$$

Later on, they introduce Chernoff Bounds (p. 68) by this equality

$$
\Pr(X \geq a) = \Pr(e^{tX} \geq e^{ta})
$$

for some "well-chosen" $t$.

It seems like the general rule would be

$$
\Pr(X \geq a) = \Pr(g(X) \geq g(a))
$$

for some function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

But I haven't seen such a general rule in any textbook. Does it always hold true? How can we prove it?

Update:

So it turns out that if $g$ is increasing, the events $\{X \geq a\}$ and $\{g(X) \geq g(a)\}$ are the same. How can one prove it?

Comment: Prove that if $g$ is an increasing function, $\{\omega:X(\omega)\ge a\}=\{\omega:g(X(\omega))\ge g(a)\}$.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's the exact point. But how to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true as long as $g$ is increasing. Indeed, if $g$ is increasing, the events $\{X \geq a\}$ and $\{g(X) \geq g(a)\}$ are the same, so of course they have the same probability:

$$\begin{align}\omega \in \{X \geq a\} & \Leftrightarrow X(\omega) \geq a  \quad \text{by defintion of the set} \\ & \Leftrightarrow g(X(\omega)) \geq g(a) \quad \text{since } g \text{ is increasing} \\ & \Leftrightarrow \omega \in \{g(X) \geq g(a)\}. \quad\text{by defintion of the set} \end{align}$$

For instance, in the first case, $|X-\mathbb{E}(X)|$ is nonnegative and the function $g : y \mapsto y^2$ is increasing in $[0, +\infty)$, so as long as $a \geq 0$, we can apply the observation above to get

$$\mathbb{P} (|X-\mathbb{E}(X)| \geq a) = \mathbb{P} (|X-\mathbb{E}(X)|^2 \geq a^2).$$

Note that this equality is false in general if $a < 0$ (exercise : find a counter-example), and our argument fails because $g : y \mapsto y^2$ is not increasing on $\mathbb{R}$.

The case of the exponential is even simpler, but requires $t > 0$ so that $g : y \mapsto e^{ty}$ is increasing.

While I don't recall seeing this principle written explicitely, it is useful to remember it in full generality. The main idea is that, the stronger constraints you have on the distribution $X$, the stronger bounds you get on its tail. Chernov bounds requires exponential moments, but gets you an exponential bound on the tail. In the other direction, I have sometimes used a version such as (for $X$, $a \geq 0)$

$$\mathbb{P} (X \geq a) = \mathbb{P} (\ln (1+X) \geq \ln(1+a)) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E} (\ln (1+X))}{\ln(1+a)},$$

which requires a very weak condition on $X$ (its logarithm needs to be integrable), but gives you a weak bound on its tail. So this family of inequalities is quite flexible.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated answer with examples! So $g$ has to be increasing. But what is the proof of this equality?

Comment: @John Doe: I've developed the proof of this equality. Do you have questions about the new version?

Comment: Thanks, yes, I got it now. So if the event "$X \geq a$" represents the set $E_1 = \{s \in \Omega : X (s) \geq a\}$ and the event "$g(X) \geq g(a)$" represents the set $E_2 = \{s \in \Omega : g(X (s)) \geq g(a)\}$, and we have to show that $E_2$ equals to $E_1$. They are, because the predicates matches, as from the definition of increasing function: $f$ is increasing if and only if $x \le y \implies  f(x) \le f(y)$